# It it possible to infer function generic type based on all rest arguments?

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

I have the code similar to following:

```
type Boxed<T> = { inner: T }

const box = <T>(inner: T): Boxed<T> => ({ inner });

function test<T extends Boxed<any>>(...args: T[]): T extends Boxed<infer I> ? I : never {
    return args[0].inner;
}
```

Here, `Boxed<T>` stand for some complex generic type, and the function is meant to effectively "unbox" its inputs into some value of the union type, based on all the inputs. But, if we simply pass in the values we need, type `T` is inferred to be the type of the first argument, and all other arguments are rejected:

```
test(box(0), box('str'));
// Argument of type 'Boxed<string>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Boxed<number>'.
```

At the same time, passing this arguments by destructuring a tuple works fine:

```
test(...[box(0), box('str')]);
// Works and has an expected type (string | number).
```

Can I do something to the function definition so that the first (clearly more ergonomic) example would work too?

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=2&pln=5&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAQg9gDwgEwDwBUB8UC8UDeUAlgHYkQBOAXFOlAL4CwAUCwMZwkDOwUARolxQMmABSly1WgEoa8JGiy5sowhMoNpAbhYsAZgFcSbYEU5RgEHhigQElksi6xEKVAEMSITGIB0-9woAcy4adABtAF1ZWlt7CEdneTdSPQ0ASWwAfih0qBpyADcNfBYocqgKCGADChIoQJDwgAZI33UKHWYmVmZLHlEBBFFm6QAafkRRAHIeCmnpbSgAemWoAEFggwBbBN44PQtwaGnktDnSIMxp4mcSOF53Li4iIJJ3PgAbaGA4KDBAu5dpYKFADkdIFBTq40CQdnxKNdfCx+sBRP5fOEhiNxpNhrNgPNpNEtCs1gB1OAUADWzk8yCgAAsng16nZICYUBDoKILiQglAAD5QOHbBEUaRAA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler infers tuple types for [generic rest parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#generic-rest-parameters) properly, when type parameter `T` has an array type constraint `<T extends Boxed<any>[]>` instead of an item constraint:

```
type Boxed<T> = { inner: T }

const box = <T>(inner: T): Boxed<T> => ({ inner });

// here 'extends Boxed<any>[]' instead of 'extends Boxed<any>'
function test<T extends Boxed<any>[]>(...args: T): T extends Boxed<infer I>[] ? I : never {
    return args[0].inner;
}

test(box(0), box('str')); // string | number 
test(...[box(0), box('str')]); // string | number
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=50#code/C4TwDgpgBAQg9gDwgEwDwBUB8UC8UDeUAlgHYkQBOAXFOlAL4CwAUCwMZwkDOwUARolxQMmABSly1WgEoa8JGiy5sowhMoNpAbhYsAZgFcSbYEU5RgEHhigQElksi6xEKVAEMSITAG0AumIAdMHuFADmXDTosrS29hCOzvJupHoaAJK%20flAA-FDpUDTkAG4a%20CxQlVAUEMAGFCRQoRE%20AAx%20geoUOsxMrMyWPKICCKKt0gA0-IiiAOQ8FLPS2lAA9KtQC6RhUAA%20UCQGALZ8lCyDwKLBgT4jY5PTo-PAi9J%20K%20ubL9t7B8enFCAA)

If you write it `T extends Boxed<any>>(...args: T[])`, TS apparently is eager to infer the whole array type by the type of first item, as all rest parameter items are supposed to have the same type.

```
declare function foo<T extends string | number>(...args: T[]): void
// foo<"bar">(...args: "bar"[]): void;
foo("bar", 1) // nono, '1' is not assignable to parameter of type '"bar"'
```

This notation resolves the generic rest parameters correctly.

```
declare function foo2<T extends (string | number)[]>(...args: T): void
// foo2<["bar", 1]>(args_0: "bar", args_1: 1): void
foo2("bar", 1)
```